how to use the MathView library correctly
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                android:id="@+id/formula_two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                auto:engine="KaTeX"
                >
            </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>

so I'm trying to use the library in a markup file
